# Convert MSword to XML/HTML on Linux

Tags: java, python, linux, perl, apache-tika

I need to convert MSWord file into XML or HTML, while preserving the structure of the file (mainly tables). I happened to find tika, which is quite powerful in extracting text from MSword files (and any files), as follows:

```
curl www.vit.org/downloads/doc/tariff.doc \ | java -jar tika-app-1.3.jar --text
```

and I can select from the options to save the output into html/XML, as follows:

```
curl www.vit.org/downloads/doc/tariff.doc \ | java -jar tika-app-1.3.jar --html
```

But the output is basically like a plain text written in HTML, so it is not possible to get the table structure and other document elements.

Is there any implementation of Tika, in Perl or Python, where it is possible to convert the document into XML/HTML while maintining the structure of its elements? Or is there any other tool on linux that can do this?

Comment: While it doesn't have tika in mind, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4200680/1979005) might be of assistance.

Comment: There is also [Antiword](http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=Ati28dqvob.8VzXPaQv4ViybvZx4?p=antiword&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t-900) which might be useful but I don't know if it can parse tables or not.

Comment: Apache Tika is able to extract Tables from Word files, it even has [a unit test for it - testWordHTML()](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-parsers/src/test/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/WordParserTest.java)! Is there something unusual about your file?

Answer (score 1):

Install OpenOffice SDK, it offers powerfull API for all kinds of documents (including conversions).

http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=7242